# Sum over vector (notation)

Tags: summation, vectors

Consider the following variable $e$, which is a $mn\times 1$ vector, where $m$ is number of countries and $n$ is number of sectors (for instance).

I want to sum over the vector, but how do I write that in a formal way? Can I use the following notation:

$\sum^{mn}_{i=1}e_i\quad\quad i=\{1,\dots,mn\}$

Comment: Seems good to me

Comment: You can also just use the usual inner product with a vector whose entries are all $1$.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot for your answers :-)